# JUnit test for testing my API client is not working, "Error: Test Engine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to execute test"

Tags: java, junit, mockito, web-api-testing, vertx-httpclient

I am new at testing with Junit and using mockito. I have created a class for my client which is supposed to send requests to an API. I have also created a class to write a simple test. When i run the test i get errors in the console and i do not know how to solve them. I have tested the API that i am sending requests to by using Postman.
Here is my code for the Client:

```
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponse;
import io.vertx.core.AsyncResult;
import io.vertx.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.core.logging.Logger;
import io.vertx.core.logging.LoggerFactory;
import io.vertx.ext.web.client.HttpRequest;
import io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClient;

public class MyClient {

    private WebClient webclient;
    private String requestURL;
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClient.class);

    public MyClient(WebClient webclient, String requestURL) {
        this.webclient = webclient;
        this.requestURL = requestURL;
    }

    public void invokeCore(JsonObject request, java.util.function.Consumer<JsonObject> func){
        webclient.post(requestURL)
        .putHeader("content-type", "application/json")
        .sendJson(request, ar -> {
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                logger.info("succeeded: " + ar.succeeded());
                logger.info("statusCode: " + ar.result().statusCode());
                logger.info("body: " + ar.result().body());
                logger.info("headers: " + ar.result().headers());
                JsonObject response = new JsonObject();
                // populate it
                func.accept(response);
             } else {
                logger.info("Executed: " + ar.cause());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is what i have written for the test class: I set up a mock WebClient and use it when creating a MyClient instance to send a request to the API.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import java.awt.List;
import javax.xml.ws.Response;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
import io.netty.util.concurrent.Future;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.ext.web.client.HttpRequest;
import io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClient;
import io.vertx.junit5.VertxExtension;
import io.vertx.junit5.VertxTestContext;

@ExtendWith(VertxExtension.class)
public class MyClientTest {

    private MyClient client;

    //set up WebClient
    private WebClient createMockWebClient(JsonObject mockResponse) {
        WebClient mockWebClient = mock(WebClient.class);
        HttpRequest<Buffer> mockRequest = mock(HttpRequest.class);

        when(mockWebClient.post(any())).thenReturn(mockRequest);
        when(mockRequest.putHeader(any(), any())).thenReturn(mockRequest);
        doAnswer(new Answer() {

            @Override
            public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                java.util.function.Consumer func = invocation.getArgument(1);
                func.accept(mockResponse);
                return null;
            }

        }).when(mockRequest).sendJson(any(), any());
        return mockWebClient;
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test response from client")
    public void test() { 
        //request being sent
        JsonObject request = new JsonObject().put("SSN", "123456789").put("Address", "123 main st").put("zip", "08888").put("dob", "012387");

        //expected response
        JsonObject response = new JsonObject().put("clientToken", "11oije311").put("clientID", "123ID");

        //test setup
        MyClient coreClient = new MyClient(createMockWebClient(new JsonObject()), "http://localhost:8080/core");

        //test steps
        coreClient.invokeCore(request, resp -> {
            assertEquals(resp.getString("clientToken"), response.getString("clientToken"));
            //end.finished();
        });
    } 
}
```

Here is the error that appears in the console when i try to run the test:
[image]

And here is the pom.xml for the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company.projectname</groupId>
    <artifactId>myprofile</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>myprofile</name>
    <description>Service to retrieve my profile</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vertx.version>3.6.0</vertx.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.1.0</junit-jupiter.version>
        <assertj-core.version>3.8.0</assertj-core.version>
        <vertx.verticle>com.company.projectname.myProfileVerticle</vertx.verticle>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web-client</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${vertx.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Vert.x Maven Plugin -->
            <!-- Auto re-deploy on code change: "mvn clean vertx:run" -->
            <!-- Warning!!! Starts detached process, must manually kill when done. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>vertx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.13</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>initialize</goal>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <redeploy>true</redeploy>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Fabric8 Maven Plugin -->
            <!-- Deploy to openshift or kubernetes: "mvn clean fabric8:deploy" -->
            <!-- Note: See src/main/fabric8/deployment.yml for deployment config -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.41</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>fabric8</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resource</goal>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Deploy to Nexus -->
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>projectnamereleases</id>
            <url>http://artifactory.company.local/artifactory/projectnameReleases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>projectnamesnapshots</id>
            <url>http://artifactory.company.local/artifactory/projectnameSnapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: I ran this in IntelJ IDEA and works fine. Maybe the issue is with how the test is executed in eclips

Comment: It works? Well that is good news! Now, just have to get it to work for me, not sure any other way to execute it in eclipse though. Any ideas?

Comment: Yea it works(but test case fails as I dont have the `mockResponse` ). Actually I dont know how eclips executes junit test cases. 
But note that `NoClassDefNoFoundError`, the class `ComparisionFailure.java` is only available in Junit 4, and you are using Junit 5.

Comment: hope this would help https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/71

Comment: Thanks! That helped out. Now the test actually runs

Comment: Great! is it the eclips issue above? Ill put an answer for future ref.

Comment: hmm, well in that thread there was a person that simply added junit 4 to their dependencies, so that's all i did to get rid of the JUnit errors that were popping up. So i dont think it is an eclipse related issue. But that link does have helpful information regarding my question.

Answer (score 1):

Check if mockito supports junit5 or maybe one of mockito or junit5 versions are outdated. Today i've lost a lot of time with a newet version of mockito according to the junit4 ones. Junit5 5.3.2 is the most recent, you are using 5.1.0. 
 Other option is you must add another dependencie.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue related to Eclips. Please see

https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/71

> removed the Jupiter dependencies to use JUnit 4 and the test worked
>   appropriately (gave correct failure/success)